# Grouping by Days Created_At

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to get a loop to post videos grouped by each day by created_at.

For example:

December 5, 2012 -
Video 9
Video 8
Video 7

December 4, 2012 -
Video 6
Video 5

December 3, 2012 -
Video 4
Video 3
Video 2
Video 1

**videos_controller:**

```
  def index
    @title = 'Hip Hop Videos, Breaking News, Videos, And Funny Shxt | HOTDROPHIPHOP'
    @description = ''
    @videos = Video.all
    @days = Video.where(:created_at == Time.today )
  end
```

**View file:**

```
<% @days.each do |day| %>

  <div class="video-date">December 4, 2012</div>

  <% @videos.each do |video| %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

I also need to get that div to show that day's date as well.

I searched around and couldn't find a solution and tried the group_by (which seemed the cleanest) but couldn't get it to work. I am a bit rusty on my Rails as I haven't touched it for months.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do this:

```
@videos = Video.where(Video.arel_table[:created_at].gteq(some_date_value))
@video_days = @videos.group_by {|video| video.created_at.to_date }
```

Where `@video_days` will be a hash in the form of `{some_date_value: [{video1}, {video2}, etc], next_date_value: [{video3}, {video4}, etc], etc...}`.

Since you are calling `.to_date` on the `created_at` field, it will drop all of the time information, effectively grouping everything by day.

You can loop through it like:

```
<% @video_days.each do |day, videos| %>
  <%= day.strftime("some format") %>
  <% videos.each do |video| %>
    <%= #output videos how you see fit %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Looks like the best way to do it, Thanks! However, having trouble with the strftime. Giving me error: undefined method `strftime' for #<Enumerator: Sat, 01 Dec 2012:step(Thu, 06 Dec 2012, 1)>. Showing as undefined method.

Comment: How are you building your loop?  I am doing this locally in rails console: `@video_days.each {|date, video| date.class}` and it is printing `Date`.  That should work.

Comment: <% @video_days.each do |day, videos| %>

  <div class="video-date"><%= day.strftime("%Y") %></div>
  
  <% videos.each do |video| %>
    
  <% end %>
  
<% end %>

Comment: Hmm, if you look at the code for `group_by` here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by, it shows that the key should be the element passed into the block, in our case, `video.created_at.to_date`.  Somehow you are getting the enumerator back, but I can't see how from here.  Can your `group_by` code?

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to use the gem [Groupdate](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate)

e.g  `User.group_by_day(:created_at).count`

Allow you to order by day, week, hour

Answer (score 1):

First of all it makes no sense to call only videos from today and then run through all videos.

I would try it this way:

## Controller

```
@videos = Video.all(:conditions => ["created_at >= ?", Date.today.at_beginning_of_month])
```

## View

```
<% Date.today.at_beginning_of_month.upto(Date.today).each do |date| %>
  <%= date %>: <%= @videos.select{|u| u.created_at == date }.title %>
<% end %>
```

It should give you a Video list with "Date: Video Title" for the actual month.

Answer (score 0):

Assumed you are using mysql and video has attribute title
I am posting the following code to help you to grasp the logic ( Surely it need re-factoring )

**Controller**

```
@videos = {}
videos =  Video.order("DATE(created_at) DESC, title ASC").select("DATE(created_at) as created_at, title, id" )

videos.collect{|x| @videos[x.created_at.to_s] = @videos[x.created_at.to_s] ? @videos[x.created_at.to_s] << x.title : [x.title]  }
```

**view**

```
<% @videos.each do |posted_date, videos| %>
  <div class="video-date"><%= Date.parse(posted_date.to_s).strftime("%b %d, %Y") %> </div> 
  <%= videos.join(", ") %>
 <% end %>
```